# Object Detection Using Raspberry Pi and Android IP Camera with Python and OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi3, ip-camera

**Here is my code that I have used for object detection using raspberry pi and Android Ip Camera. Here I'm not getting any output and the code does not provide any errors. Can someone figure out what is the error?**

```
import urllib.request
import cv2
import numpy as np
import datetime
import math

#global variables
width = 0
height = 0
EntranceCounter = 0
ExitCounter = 0
MinCountourArea = 3000  #Adjust ths value according to your usage
BinarizationThreshold = 70  #Adjust ths value according to your usage
OffsetRefLines = 150  #Adjust ths value according to your usage

#Check if an object in entering in monitored zone
def CheckEntranceLineCrossing(y, CoorYEntranceLine, CoorYExitLine):
  AbsDistance = abs(y - CoorYEntranceLine)  

  if ((AbsDistance <= 2) and (y < CoorYExitLine)):
                 return 1
  else:
                 return 0
#Check if an object in exitting from monitored zone
def CheckExitLineCrossing(y, CoorYEntranceLine, CoorYExitLine):
    AbsDistance = abs(y - CoorYExitLine)    

    if ((AbsDistance <= 2) and (y > CoorYEntranceLine)):
                   return 1
    else:

                   return 0
```

**This is the code i have used to obtain the video stream from my IP camera**

```
ReferenceFrame = None

while True:
  camera=cv2.VideoCapture("http://192.168.1.6:8080/shot.jpg")
  camera.set(3,640)
  camera.set(4,480)
  (ret,Frame)=camera.read()
  height = np.size(Frame,0)
  width = np.size(Frame,1)

#if cannot grab a frame, this program ends here.
  if not ret:
    break
```

**This is the code part i have used to display the lines and frame for object detection and object counting**

```
#gray-scale convertion and Gaussian blur filter applying
    GrayFrame = cv2.cvtColor(Frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    GrayFrame = cv2.GaussianBlur(GrayFrame, (21, 21), 0)
    
    if ReferenceFrame is None:
        ReferenceFrame = GrayFrame
        continue

    #Background subtraction and image binarization
    FrameDelta = cv2.absdiff(ReferenceFrame, GrayFrame)
    FrameThresh = cv2.threshold(FrameDelta, BinarizationThreshold, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    
    #Dilate image and find all the contours
    FrameThresh = cv2.dilate(FrameThresh, None, iterations=2)
    _, cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(FrameThresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    QttyOfContours = 0

    #plot reference lines (entrance and exit lines) 
    CoorYEntranceLine = (height / 2)-OffsetRefLines
    CoorYExitLine = (height / 2)+OffsetRefLines
    cv2.line(Frame, (0,CoorYEntranceLine), (width,CoorYEntranceLine), (255, 0, 0), 2)
    cv2.line(Frame, (0,CoorYExitLine), (width,CoorYExitLine), (0, 0, 255), 2)


    #check all found countours
    for c in cnts:
        #if a contour has small area, it'll be ignored
        if cv2.contourArea(c) < MinCountourArea:
            continue

        QttyOfContours = QttyOfContours+1    

        #draw an rectangle "around" the object
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(Frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

        #find object's centroid
        CoordXCentroid = (x+x+w)/2
        CoordYCentroid = (y+y+h)/2
        ObjectCentroid = (CoordXCentroid,CoordYCentroid)
        cv2.circle(Frame, ObjectCentroid, 1, (0, 0, 0), 5)
        
        if (CheckEntranceLineCrossing(CoordYCentroid,CoorYEntranceLine,CoorYExitLine)):
            EntranceCounter += 1

        if (CheckExitLineCrossing(CoordYCentroid,CoorYEntranceLine,CoorYExitLine)):  
            ExitCounter += 1

    print ("Total countours found: "+str(QttyOfContours))

    #Write entrance and exit counter values on frame and shows it
    cv2.putText(Frame, "Entrances: {}".format(str(EntranceCounter)), (10, 50),
                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (250, 0, 1), 2)
    cv2.putText(Frame, "Exits: {}".format(str(ExitCounter)), (10, 70),
                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)




   
  cv2.imshow('Salida',Frame)
  cv2.waitKey(1);

# When everything done, release the capture 
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct code

```
import numpy as np
import math

def nothing(x):
    pass
width=0
height=0
EntranceCounter = 0
OffsetRefLines = 150
ExitCounter = 0
BinarizationThreshold = 70
MinCountourArea = 3000

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0);
path="http://192.168.1.6:8080/video"
cap.open(path)
ReferenceFrame = None

#Check if an object in entering in monitored zone
def CheckEntranceLineCrossing(y, CoorYEntranceLine, CoorYExitLine):
  AbsDistance = abs(y - CoorYEntranceLine)  

  if ((AbsDistance <= 2) and (y < CoorYExitLine)):
                 return 1
  else:
                 return 0

#Check if an object in exitting from monitored zone
def CheckExitLineCrossing(y, CoorYEntranceLine, CoorYExitLine):
    AbsDistance = abs(y - CoorYExitLine)    

    if ((AbsDistance <= 2) and (y > CoorYEntranceLine)):
                   return 1
    else:

                   return 0


#cv2.namedWindow("Tracking")
cv2.createTrackbar("LH", "Tracking", 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("LS", "Tracking", 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("LV", "Tracking", 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("UH", "Tracking", 255, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("US", "Tracking", 255, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("UV", "Tracking", 255, 255, nothing)

while True:
    #frame = cv2.imread('smarties.png')
  if cap.isOpened():
      rval, frame = cap.read()
    

  while rval:
    rval,frame = cap.read()
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    hsv = cv2.GaussianBlur(hsv, (21, 21), 0)

    if ReferenceFrame is None:
        ReferenceFrame = hsv
        continue
    
    #Background subtraction and image binarization
    FrameDelta = cv2.absdiff(ReferenceFrame, hsv)
    FrameThresh = cv2.threshold(FrameDelta, 25, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

    #Dilate image and find all the contours
    FrameThresh = cv2.dilate(FrameThresh, None, iterations=2)
    cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(FrameThresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    QttyOfContours = 0
    
    #plot reference lines (entrance and exit lines) 
    cv2.line(frame, (0,170), (2000,170), (255, 0, 0), 5)

    cv2.line(frame, (0,470), (2000,470), (0, 0, 255), 5)

    #check all found countours
    for c in cnts:
        #if a contour has small area, it'll be ignored
        if cv2.contourArea(c) < MinCountourArea:
            continue

        QttyOfContours = QttyOfContours+1    

        #draw an rectangle "around" the object
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)


        #find object's centroid
        CoordXCentroid = int(x+x+w)/2
        CoordYCentroid = int(y+y+h)/2
        ObjectCentroid = (x,y)
        cv2.circle(frame, ObjectCentroid, 2, (0, 255, 0), 5)

        if (CheckEntranceLineCrossing(CoordYCentroid,170,470)):
            EntranceCounter += 1

        if (CheckExitLineCrossing(CoordYCentroid,170,470)):  
            ExitCounter += 1

        print ("Total countours found: "+str(QttyOfContours))


        
        #Write entrance and exit counter values on frame and shows it
    cv2.putText(frame, "Entrances: {}".format(str(EntranceCounter)), (10, 50),
    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (250, 0, 1), 2)
    cv2.putText(frame, "Exits: {}".format(str(ExitCounter)), (10, 110),
    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (0, 0, 255), 2)



    imS = cv2.resize(frame, (400, 400))                    # Resize image
    #imSS = cv2.resize(mask, (200, 200)) 
    #imSSS = cv2.resize(frame, (200, 200))   
    cv2.imshow("frame", imS)
    #cv2.imshow("mask", imSS)
    #cv2.imshow("res", imSSS)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
       break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```